# Given a continuous mapping $f$ find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 nf(x)e^{-nx}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Given a continuous mapping $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 nf(x)e^{-nx}$$ 
Now I'm clueless, however I've had to solve a similar question
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\frac1{\sqrt n}}nf(x)e^{-nx}$$
I've did this by noting that since $f$ is continuous it attains it max/min on the interval $[0,\frac1{\sqrt n}]$, if we let $f(a)$ be the minimum and $f(b)$ the maximum then
$$\int_0^{\frac1{\sqrt n}}nf(a)e^{-nx}= f(a)(-e^{-\sqrt n}+1)\leq \int_0^{\frac1{\sqrt n}}nf(x)e^{-nx}\leq f(b)(-e^{-\sqrt n}+1)=\int_0^{\frac1{\sqrt n}}nf(b)e^{-nx}$$
So
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(a)(-e^{-\sqrt n}+1)\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\frac1{\sqrt n}}nf(x)e^{-nx}\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}f(b)(-e^{-\sqrt n}+1)$$
So
$$f(a)\leq\int_0^{\frac1{\sqrt n}}nf(x)e^{-nx}\leq f(b)$$
Since $a,b\in[0,\frac1{\sqrt n}]$ and $f$ is continuous means that $f(a)=f(b)=f(0)$. However I can't do the same for the $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 nf(x)e^{-nx}$$

Comment: @T.Bongers That is not correct.  $\int_0^1 ne^{-nx}\,dx=1-e^{-n}\to 1$.  The DCT doesn't apply directly; what did you have in mind for the dominating function for $ne^{-nx}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\int_0^1 ne^{-nx}f(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\xi_{x\in[0,n]}(x)f(x/n)\,dx$$

where $\xi_{x\in[0,n]}(x)$ is the indicator function.  Now apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: So $f_n = e^{-x}\xi_{x\in[0,n]}(x)f(x/n)$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n=e^{-x}f(0)=f$ then $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\xi_{x\in[0,n]}(x)f(x/n)dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}f(0)dx$ if I understand correctly.

Comment: Yes, you have it.  Well done!

Comment: The key is to note that $|e^{-x}f(x/n)\xi_{[0,n]}(x)|\le \max_{x\in[0,1]}(f(x))\,e^{-x}$, which is integrable.  Then, we can justify interchanging the limit with the integral and arrive at $f(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (without Dominated Convergence Theorem). Note that by the continuity of $f$ at $0$,  for $\epsilon>0$ there is $0<\delta\leq 1$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)|\leq\epsilon$ for $x\in [0,\delta]$. Hence
$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_0^1 ne^{-nx}f(x)dx-f(0)\right|&=\left|\int_0^1 ne^{-nx}(f(x)-f(0))dx-f(0)e^{-n}\right|\\
&\leq \int_0^{\delta} ne^{-nx}|f(x)-f(0)|dx+\int_{\delta}^1 ne^{-nx}|f(x)-f(0)|dx+|f(0)|e^{-n}\\
&\leq (1-e^{-n\delta})\epsilon+(e^{-n\delta}-e^{-n})(\max_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)|+|f(0)|)+|f(0)|e^{-n}.
\end{align}$$
Can you take it form here?

Comment: Yeah, the RHS of inequality tends to $\epsilon$ as $n\to\infty$ hence $\int_0^1 ne^{-nx}f(x)dx=f(0)$, thanks for the hint, and an alternative instead of dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @kingW3 Well done!

Answer (score 1):

> I thought it might be instructive to present another way forward that circumvents the use of the Dominated Convergence Theorem.  To that end, we now proceed.

---

First, we note that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x|<\delta$.  For a given $\epsilon>0$, fix such a $0<\delta<1$.

---

Next, we write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 ne^{-nx}f(x)\,dx&=\int_0^1 ne^{-nx}f(0)\,dx+\int_0^1 ne^{-nx}\left(f(x)-f(0)\right)\,dx\\\\
&=f(0)(1-e^{-n})+\int_0^1 ne^{-nx}\left(f(x)-f(0)\right)\,dx\\\\
&=f(0)(1-e^{-n})\\\\
&+\int_0^\delta ne^{-nx}\left(f(x)-f(0)\right)\,dx\\\\
&+\int_\delta^1 ne^{-nx}\left(f(x)-f(0)\right)\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$

---

We can estimate the second term on the right-hand side of $(1)$ as

$$\left|\int_0^\delta ne^{-nx}\left(f(x)-f(0)\right)\,dx\right|\le \epsilon (1-e^{-n})\tag2$$

while we can estimate the third term as

$$\left|\int_\delta^1 ne^{-nx}\left(f(x)-f(0)\right)\,dx\right|\le 2\max_{x\in [0,1]}(f(x))\,(e^{-n\delta}-1)\tag3$$

---

Taking the limit as $n\to \infty$ in $(2)$ and $(3)$ we find that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\int_0^1 ne^{-nx}(f(x)-f(0))\,dx\right|\le \epsilon$$

Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we must have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 ne^{-nx}(f(x)-f(0))\,dx=0$$

whence we find the coveted limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 ne^{-nx}f(x)\,dx=f(0)$$